# QT Creator Android Handler int thread call crash

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator

I have a project in a Android studio.
Now i want to write this programm in a QT Creator.
But i have a problem.
In main Activity i have a Handle

```
public class MyCustomAppActivity extends QtActivity {
public static   Handler hl;
.......
hl = new Handler(new Handler.Callback()
           {
               @Override
               public boolean handleMessage(Message msg)
               {
                   Toast.makeText(MyCustomAppActivity.this, "" +  msg.what, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   return false;
               }
           });
```

And i call this handler from Thread

```
enter code here

class MyRun implements Runnable {
.......
Message msg1 = new Message();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("Key", "The Key's Value");
msg1.setData(bundle);
MyCustomAppActivity.hl.sendMessage(msg);

enter code here
```

But here my programm crash.
However in Android Studio it was a good.
Help me please.